# xmodmap pointer setting doesn't affect all applications

Tags: 14.04, xorg, touchpad, xmodmap, mouse-scroll

I have a laptop designed for windows 8 and running ubuntu 14.04. Because it is designed for windows 8, the touchpad is backwards. The scroll bars on the side and top are reversed so that it feels like the opposite of a scroll wheel. To try and solve the problem I created the file "~/.Xmodmap" with the following text

```
pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12
```

This works for some applications. Google Chrome now works properly and scrolling is back to scroll wheel style. Firefox also works properly and so does the terminal and libre office. Some applications however do not accept the new settings and stubbornly remain in backwards scroll mode. Examples are gedit, the ubuntu software centre and the document viewer.

How do I get the scroll behaviour to be consistently like a standard scroll wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

> There is a known bug:
>
> Every time a keycode expression is evaluated, the server generates a
>   MappingNotify event on every client. This can cause some thrashing.
>   All of the changes should be batched together and done at once.
>   Clients that receive keyboard input and ignore MappingNotify events
>   will not notice any changes made to keyboard mappings.
>
> Xmodmap should generate "add" and "remove" expressions automatically
>   whenever a keycode that is already bound to a modifier is changed.
>
> There should be a way to have the remove expression accept keycodes as
>   well as keysyms for those times when you really mess up your mappings.

Check it out in order to know if it has to do with your problem.

Just for curiosity, Are you using the xmodmap program in the next synopsis?

```
xmodmap [-options ...] [filename]
```

If no, go to this link:

[XMODMAP Manual Page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xmodmap.1.html)

Comment: This is the default. The problem is that the new setting isn't honoured in all applications. With this setting, everything is the wrong way around. With the setting i tried, some things become correct but not all.